# i use HATHOR-2 nd i make file with makefile but when i give command of make it says --make: *** No rule to make target 'demo', needed by 'all'. Stop

Tags: make

the following is the make file

[image: image showing make: *** No rule to make target 'demo', needed by 'all'. Stop.]

```make
ifeq ($(LHAPDF),)
   LHAPDF = $(HOME)/local/lhapdf
endif

LHAPDFINC = $(shell $(LHAPDF)/bin/lhapdf-config --incdir)
LHAPDFLIB = $(shell $(LHAPDF)/bin/lhapdf-config --libdir)

HATHORPATH = .

CC  = gcc
CXX = g++
FC  = gfortran
AR  = ar
RANLIB = ranlib

IFLAGS = -I. -I$(LHAPDFINC) -I$(HATHORPATH)/include
MYLIBS =  -L $(HATHORPATH)/lib -lHathor -L $(LHAPDFLIB) -lLHAPDF -lff

LFLAGS := $(MYLIBS) $(LFLAGS) -lgfortranbegin -lgfortran -lm

# default configuration
CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -O2 -Wall

DEMOS =  demo demo-hathor-1.3

all: $(DEMOS)

%: %.cxx
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -f $(DEMOS) 

distclean: clean
```

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: and, as the error message says, you have no rule that describes how to make the "demo" target, so it's really not clear what your question would have been!